# Using multi choice mode in grid view

Tags: android, image, multichoiceitems

I am creating app for viewing images.So, I decided to implement multi choice deleting for pictures in grid view.I am using setMultiChoiceModeListener method.Everything woks fine, but I have one problem...I can't close contextual menu in  onDestroyActionMode method.I always get such exception:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1656)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:972)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:78)
        at com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageList$1.onDestroyActionMode(ImageList.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6604)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3048)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1656)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:972)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:78)
        at com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageList$1.onDestroyActionMode(ImageList.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6604)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3048)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1656)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:972)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:78)
        at com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageList$1.onDestroyActionMode(ImageList.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6604)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3048)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1656)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:972)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:78)
        at com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageList$1.onDestroyActionMode(ImageList.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6604)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3048)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1656)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:972)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:78)
        at com.example.vasylpaliy.mediaview.ImageList$1.onDestroyActionMode(ImageList.java:91)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:6604)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3048)
```

Here is code:

```
view.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        private boolean isDeleted;
        private ArrayList<String> imageItems;
        {
            imageItems=new ArrayList<String>();
            isDeleted=false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            imageItems.add(imagePaths.get(position));
            mode.setTitle("Selected:" + Integer.toString(view.getCheckedItemCount()));
            imageAdapter.setCheckMark(position);
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.multiple_audio, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.multiple_audio_select_all:
                {
                    imageItems=imagePaths;
                    for(int i=0;i<imageItems.size();i++)
                        view.setItemChecked(i,true);
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.multiple_audio_deleting:
                {
                    deleteItems(imageItems);
                    isDeleted=true;
                    onDestroyActionMode(mode);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            if(mode!=null)
                mode.finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` will cause a call of `onDestroyActionMode()` it will not set your mode to null.

So all you need is:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
     // nothing here ;)
}
```

Also note that, if you want to finish your actionmode here:

```
 case R.id.multiple_audio_deleting:
     {
     deleteItems(imageItems);
     isDeleted=true;
     onDestroyActionMode(mode);
     break;
 }
```

change it to:

```
case R.id.multiple_audio_deleting:
     {
     deleteItems(imageItems);
     isDeleted=true;
     mode.finish();
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your StackoverflowError is caused by your implementation of "onActionItemClicked()" and "onDestroyActionMode()":

With each execution of `mode.finish();` in "onDestroyActionMode()", the framework will call precisely this method yet another time, so you are creating a kind of infinite loop.

According to the sample from the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB), especially the part about **Enabling batch contextual actions in a ListView or GridView**, you should change two things:

**1.** In your implementation of "onActionItemClicked()", call

```
mode.finish();
```

instead of "onDestroyActionMode()".

**2.** In your "onDestroyActionMode()", you don't need to call "finish()". You can override this method to

> ...make any necessary updates to the activity when the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.